# How to change launcher application on cyanogenmod 11?

Tags: cyanogenmod, launcher

I've updated my Cyanogenmod 11, and I found that the Google experience launcher is not available anymore. Instead I'm forced to use trebuchet (or something like that) with the option to have the google now cards.

But I'd like to have GEL instead! How should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried installing it from Google Play? Not sure which one it is (as it's not exactly my favorite) – but maybe you mean [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher)?

Comment: That did it! I missed it because I previously installed google now...

Comment: OK, so maybe I make it an answer for you to accept – so it gets clear your issue has been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Google Launcher* is [available at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher) – so you can install it like you would install any other app.